# ListPlot with a histogram of values on the vertical axis

Tags: plotting

I have a time-dependent plot of points along the x-axis. These values will have a certain distribution when projected onto the y-axis.    How can I plot a corresponding histogram of these values,  based/started from  the  y-axis  (i.e. a  histogram tilted by 90 degrees)?

---

```
plotList={{592.5, -0.00043431}, 
ErrorBar[0.000278321]}}, {{{655., -0.000128374}, 
ErrorBar[0.000276677]}}, {{{696.5, 0.000016092}, 
ErrorBar[0.00029538]}}, {{{625., 0.0000796552}, 
ErrorBar[0.00028206]}}, {{{682., -0.000117011}, 
ErrorBar[0.000249439]}}, {{{719., -0.0000366048}, 
ErrorBar[0.000246761]}}, {{{917., -0.000133364}, 
ErrorBar[0.000321279]}}, {{{931.5, 0.0000925862}, 
ErrorBar[0.000232181]}}, {{{946., 0.000165025}, 
ErrorBar[0.000274432]}}, {{{860., 0.000122414}, 
ErrorBar[0.000313476]}}, {{{872., 0.0000972414}, 
ErrorBar[0.000251361]}}, {{{888., 0.0000806513}, 
ErrorBar[0.000278619]}}, {{{970., 0.0000185057}, 
ErrorBar[0.000288043]}}, {{{991., 0.000129885}, 
ErrorBar[0.000323213]}}, {{{1005.5, -0.0000224138}, 
ErrorBar[0.000297048]}}, {{{1046., 0.0000600726}, 
ErrorBar[0.000321164]}}, {{{1058.5, 0.000110739}, 
ErrorBar[0.000274034]}}, {{{1076., 0.000014751}, 
ErrorBar[0.000244478]}}, {{{1120., -0.0000457854}, 
ErrorBar[0.000316175]}}, {{{1132., 0.0000683744}, 
ErrorBar[0.000299614]}}, {{{1155., 0.0000898276}, 
ErrorBar[0.00024668]}}, {{{1205., 0.000136991}, 
ErrorBar[0.0003138]}}, {{{1218., 7.91075*10^-6}, 
ErrorBar[0.000296818]}}, {{{1234., 0.000140961}, 
ErrorBar[0.00027316]}}, {{{1276.5, 0.0000406897}, 
ErrorBar[0.000296665]}}, {{{1289., 0.000116878}, 
ErrorBar[0.0002688]}}, {{{1302., 0.000123765}, 
ErrorBar[0.000265536]}}, {{{1393., -0.0000846983}, 
ErrorBar[0.000274375]}}, {{{1404.5, 0.0000106985}, 
ErrorBar[0.000265274]}}, {{{1418., 0.000141379}, 
ErrorBar[0.00032606]}}, {{{768., -0.0000805911}, 
ErrorBar[0.000255396]}}, {{{783., 0.000107524}, 
ErrorBar[0.000264735]}}, {{{797.5, 0.000117845}, 
ErrorBar[0.000311275]}}
```

Comment: Give your data.

Comment: And some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

> i.e. a histogram tilted by 90 degrees

Look at [`BarOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarOrigin.html),

```
SeedRandom[420];
data = Table[RandomChoice[
    RandomVariate /@
     {NormalDistribution[3, 2],
      NormalDistribution[-5, 1]}]
   , 200];

Show[
 Histogram[data, BarOrigin -> Left],
 ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
 ]
```

[image]